# Как отправить cookie с помощью socket?

Tags: c#, сокет, cookie, proxy

Есть прокси сервер, который принимает и отдает http запросы:

```
TcpListener myTCP = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(_ProxyAddress), _ProxyPort);
myTCP.Start();
while (true)
{
// ждем запросы от клиента
    if (myTCP.Pending())
    {
        // создаем поток
        Thread t = new Thread(ExecuteRequest);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start(myTCP.AcceptSocket());//слушаем
    }
}
```

При запросе на авторизацию в ответе возвращаются cookie (sessionid). Как прицепить их к следующему запросу, используя Socket и не используя HttpWebRequest и HttpWebResponse?

Comment: Чем вам не подходят готовые WebClient, HttpClient или HttpWebRequest?

Comment: А откуда взялось требование не использовать `WebClient` или `HttpClient`? Вы хотите вручную заимплементировать HTTP поверх TCP? Тогда вы знали, на что идёте, расхлёбывайте сами.

Comment: [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) вам в руки

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать более высокоуровневый `HttpListener`, практически без потерь по производительности. Получаете контекст запроса с заголовками и прочими преимуществами.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитать HTTP заголовок, будет что типа

> GET http://localhost/ADM.WebSite/ HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
>   Referer: http://localhost/ADM.WebSite/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fADM.WebSite%2f
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L0FETS5XZWJTaXRl0=JiaBlDGifg6h-hFScHSpe3qGHIJt9jmNH8yRHJn-kVNar0V1GNRnVNliL8xnagN_2H_gOolvSdi1H6tPIWnFo4Cl2eknWZyQSJ0TYsYFDWXrfaCVZh3YHCvPTTsR11m8wR0VZCCLbbcTvHSDPYwPwA2; .ASPXAUTH=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; ASP.NET_SessionId=0ww4em4p0koninlofbwtpucx

разобрать и вытащить оттуда значения cookie, среди которых найти sessionid.